# python how does this dictionary get populated has data attribute on return

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, pack, unpack

```
    self.mem_writes = {}

def get_memory(self, address, size):
    try:
        return self.mem_writes[(address, size)].data
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return None
```

`mem_writes` isn't used anywhere else except for this function I wonder how does it ever get populated with data?
I assume it's a dictionary holding address with size as the key value and the data is binded as the value am I wrong here?

I still can't figure out how it's getting populated I can't even test this on Python (command line)
I get error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Yet the original script runs without any errors

I was looking for anything in the script with .data and this is all I found

```
import struct

class DWORD(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = struct.pack('<I', value)
```

But there is no connection with `DWORD` to `int` that links them up together.. yes I know DWORD the name is a unsigned int but that means nothing and yes `DWORD` class isn't used anywhere in the script so it must be linked somehow but I can't figure that out, it must be a class that's not implemented yet.

I was looking at all the get_memory calls and they look like this

```
value = self.converter.get_memory(addr, 4)
value, = struct.unpack('<I', value)

data = self.converter.get_memory(ind_addr + ii, 1)
index, = struct.unpack('<B', data)

data = self.converter.get_memory(table_addr + ii*scale, 4)
addr, = struct.unpack('<I', data)
```

does that coma right before the struct.unpack is used to put stuff back into .data of the return result of the get_memory I find it really strange since I have never encountered this in any other programming languages.

Where the value of the get_memory gets retrieved is pretty easy to find.. it looks like this

```
try:
    data = get_memory(address, 16)
except NotImplementedError, e:
    print 'Could not get memory for address %X' % address
    raise e
```

yes the data in the case above should become a byte array of 16 bytes.

Here is the original script: https://github.com/matpow2/cuwo/blob/master/terraingen/converter.py

Comment: Did you search the imports?

Comment: I did the only ones I could find in the folder were pefile.py and config.py nothing there in either of them and how can imports affect a built-in dictionary type anyways? they have one called `ctypes.c_int32` which i can't find which could possibly hold something important but i think it's probably also one of those built-in packages

Comment: Alright I found something about `ctypes` https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html  `15.17.1.6. Calling functions with your own custom data types`  is that it? still I can't seem to understand how the data gets set even with that example if it already gets returned out